# How to make a Page Accesible .POST Only

Tags: php, html

I've tried typing in a URL before, and it told me "This action is available via POST only. Please press the back button and try again." What is the code to make that happen on my website?

Comment: Your script is free to examine the method used to submit the request and respond differently depending on that method. We're not going to provide you the code to do this; try to write it yourself and ask a *specific* question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should just test for the presence of the form values you're expecting, like this `! isset($_POST['email'])`. If you really want to restrict to POST queries only, simply check [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Don't forget to send the [correct HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
  header('HTTP/1.1 405 Method not allowed');
  header('Allow: POST');
  die('This action is available via POST only');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] and act accordingly.
http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$_SERVER` superglobal.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    // Conditionally deny the request
}
```